# Reactjs modal not displayed

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to display a modal when I click on a td. The code of the modal is in another function. But this modal is not displayed.
Here is the code (the td is inside a map as I'm displaying a list of members so I'm using Object.keys(membersArray).map()).

```
<td onClick={() => {return this.handleClickToOpen(key, membersArray) }} style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>{membersArray[key].length + "members\nClick for names "}</td>
```

And the other functions I'm calling (Here I'm not displaying the members list because I just want to test wether the modal is displayed).

```
handleClickToOpen = (key, membersArray) => {
        this.setState({ showListOfMembers: true });
         this.showMembers(key, membersArray)
      };
      
    handleToClose = () => {
       this.setState({ showListOfMembers: false });
      };
showMembers(key, membersArray) {

        let {showListOfMembers} = this.state 


        return (
            <div stlye={{}}>
              <Dialog open={showListOfMembers} onClose={this.handleToClose}>
                <DialogTitle>{"How are you?"}</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                  <DialogContentText>
                    I am Good, Hope the same for you!
                  </DialogContentText>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                  <Button onClick={this.handleToClose} 
                          color="primary" autoFocus>
                    Close
                  </Button>
                </DialogActions>
              </Dialog>
            </div>
          );
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you everyone !

Comment: On the off-topic: are you working on a project or are you just getting started? If it's the latter I suggest you to use functional components as it's much easy on the human eye and to code, nobody starts projects with Classes in React in 2023. Onto the topic are you rendering this component that returns this modal into the component that's supposed to open it? Like if `onClick` you are just updating the `showListOfMembers` state to `true` it won't do much without rendering it.